# Реализация telegram bot для приветствия новых юзеров в чате

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Который день не могу найти примеры реализации бота, (на питоне), который бы приветствовал новых юзеров в чате. Кто знает, как реализовать?

Answer (score 5):

```
from telebot import TeleBot 

bot = TeleBot('token')


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['new_chat_members'])
def greeting(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, text='hello')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

> The Message object also has a `content_typeattribute`, which defines
>   the type of the Message. `content_type` can be one of the following
>   strings: `text`, `audio`, `document`, `photo`, `sticker`, `video`,
>   `video_note`, `voice`, `location`, `contact`, `new_chat_members`,
>   `left_chat_member`, `new_chat_title`, `new_chat_photo`,
>   `delete_chat_photo`, `group_chat_created`, `supergroup_chat_created`,
>   `channel_chat_created`, `migrate_to_chat_id`, `migrate_from_chat_id`,
>   `pinned_message`.
>
> You can use some types in one function. Example:
>
> ```
> content_types=["text", "sticker", "pinned_message", "photo", "audio"]
> ```

[Источник](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI#types)