# telegram bot для приветствия новых пользователей в чате

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Как сделать так, чтобы бот приветствовал новых пользователей в групповом чате?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Реализация telegram bot для приветствия новых юзеров в чате](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/865354/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-telegram-bot-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%8e%d0%b7%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5)

Comment: На вопрос сформулированый в такой форме очевидно верным будет простой и лаконичный ответ, отвечающий на вопрос полностью и недвузначно - запрограммировать.